# Sending information through the parameters of the FLASK URL - (SERVER IIS WINDOWS)

Tags: python, flask, iis

I created a server to receive data from a data_logger,

It is connected through a flask api that I created, and stores the data in a posgreSQL database.

When I run the api locally, through the terminal, I can send hundreds of thousands of data per minutes. But when I do the Deploy on IIS windows it limits me a lot.

I already changed the "maxURL" and "MaxQueryString"
The sending is done with the 'POST' method, inside a url parameter.

WEB.CONFIG IS LIKE THIS:

requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"
requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" maxUrl="4294967295" maxQueryString="4294967295" /
</requestFiltering

Exemplo da url>>> machineserver.ddns.net:5000/shippingofroute?parameter=RR108102220300020900209002090020900786;RR308102221300715707157071570715700840;RR108102222309876503452987650345200104;RR108102223300320203202032020320200890;

unfortunately I still haven't found a solution to this problem, I need to send a lot of data from several loggers, locally the bank and the API work perfectly.

Every help is welcome, thankss!!!!

Comment: Is there any error message in the log?

Comment: alright.
I managed to resolve this error.
Instead of passing the values ​​in the url parameters I send a json through the request body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright.
I managed to resolve this error.
Instead of passing the values ​​in the url parameters I send a json through the request body